# How to extract frames as individual webp/jxl files from a mov file with H.264/265 format?

Tags: hevc, vips, jpeg-xl

I have a movie file like `example.mov`, in H.264 or H.265 (HEVC) format (from iPhone) and I want to extract all frames as individual image files in lossless webp format and jxl format.

I've looked for command lines or a python solution.

`ffmpeg` does work work for mov -> webp, but it's quite slow.

```bash
ffmpeg -i example.mov -codec libwebp -lossless 0 VIDEO-0_%d.webp
```

I'm wondering if is there a solution using `libvips` but I only found heif (image) -> webp.

```bash
vips heifload test.heic test.webp
```

And I'm not even sure if it's lossless.

A solution that would use multiprocessing for speed up would be ideal as well.

Comment: You can use `vips copy x y.webp[lossless]` to write lossless webp. vips can't read MOV though, so I don't think it'll work for you.

Comment: LEADTOOLS SDKs can convert video to still images (both lossy and lossess) using the [Still Image Writer filter](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-still-image-writer.html) or the [Video Callback filter](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-video-callback-filter-2-0.html). (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendor). I tested this with a video resolution of 720 x 404 and saved 61,000 WebP frames at a rate of about 1500 frames per minute. My test PC was over 7 years old, so using a better machine should give you better performance.